# How do you delete and replace a .mp3 file using the Storage class in Laravel

Tags: laravel, audio, controller, storage

I am building a tool that allows users to edit audio. My plan is this:

1. retrieve audio text from database and generate audio
2. store audio file in the Laravel storage system
3. if the user edits the audio, delete the old one
4. put the new audio file in the same location

However, I can easily delete the .mp3 file. But when I go to recreate the file the one that is played for the user is the old audio file. It will work sometimes but only every now and then.

My controller code

```
//this is called when the user retrieves the audio the first time and this is working fine
public function getAudioInfo(Request $request){
        ...
        $audio = audio.mp3; //just for an example, this holds an .mp3 file
        $path = "Audio/audio_type/audio_sub_type/";;
        $audio_name = $name.".mp3";
        $save_path = 'public/'.$path.$audio_name;
        Storage::put($save_path , $audio_file);

        //store needed variables in the session
        Session::put('audio_url', Storage::url($path)); //used to listen to the audio
        Session::put('audio_path', 'public/'.$path.$audio_name); //used to get the audio on html
        return back()->with('success', 'Audio retrieved');
    }

//this is where is breaks, it will delete the file but when it replaces it still plays the old
//audio for the user
    public function displayUpdatedAudio(Request $request){
        //session variables needed
        $audio_path = Session::pull('audio_path');
        ...
        $audio_file = new_audio.mp3;
        //delete old file
        Storage::delete($audio_path);
        Storage::put($audio_path, $audio_file); //this is where it seems to fail
 
        return back()->with('success', 'Audio retrieved');
    }
```

my route

```
    Route::get('preview_update', 'Admin\AudioController@displayUpdate')->name('preview_update');
```

my html

```
        <form id="preview-audio" method="GET" action="{{ route('preview_update') }}">
            <div class="input-field">
                <audio controls id="audio">
                    <source src="@if(Session::has('audio_url')) <?php echo Session::get('audio_url'); ?> @endif" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="listen-submit-update">Get Updated Audio</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Did you try to flush the session and send you new values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mp3 file is probably cached by the browser and never requested a second time. In order to avoid the browser cache, you either need to:

- add some random stuff to your mp3 file URL

```
https://example.com/1.mp3?r=123
```

- or set the no-cache headers to the server response so that the browser will not cache your file:

```
->withHeaders([
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'Expires' => '0',
]);
```